# Where does the code for WPF a window/usercontrol resource go?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radio-button

I'm trying to follow [this](http://wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html) tutorial, but I'm not clear on where the code for the `EnumMatchToBooleanConverter` class is supposed to go. I assumed that it would go in the code-behind file (i.e. view.xaml.cs), but then I get an error along the lines of `The type EnumMatchToBooleanConverter was not found` when I try declaring the resource in the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a small WPF project should have the following approximate folder structure:

- ProjectName

  - Converters
  - DataAccess
  - DataTypes
  - Images
  - ViewModels
  - Views

Converters is the folder where you should store your `Converter` classes. After developing WPF for a while, you'll find that your collection of `Converter` classes will increase in size. Each of these folders contain classes that we map to related namespaces. In the case of the `Converter` classes, it would typically be like this:

```
namespace ProjectName.Converters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Brush))]
    public class BoolToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

For the `DataTypes` classes, you'd use something like:

```
namespace ProjectName.DataTypes
{
    public class SomeDataType
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As @LordTakkera correctly mentioned, you'd then need to reference these classes in XAML by defining a XAML namespace like so:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:ProjectName.Converters"
```

Then you could define the `Converter` in the `Resources` section like this:

```
<Converters:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="BoolToBrushConverter" />
```

See the Data Conversion section of the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#data_conversion) page on MSDN for more information. The [`IValueConverter` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN is another useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

EnumMatchToBooleanConverter in this case is its own class. You should be able to declare it in a existing code behind, but I would stick it into its own file just to be sure. 
Visual Studio can be dumb when finding resources, so you should rebuild the project in case errors are still shown.

Answer (score 0):

Converters (like all other classes) belong in their own file.

Then, you just need to include the namespace in your XAML:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
```

Also, try rebuilding/running the app as the XAML "intellisense" often won't update what is in the namespaces until a build has taken place.